# Rails - delete_all or destroy_all not working on production server but working fine in development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where I need to periodically delete search logs from a model. For this I am using a rake task with the syntax **model.destroy_all**, it is working fine in development server. However, nothing seems to be happening on production server.

Both development and production servers are using Ubuntu Server 10.04, Rails 3.0.7, Mysql Database. Did you face similar situation before?

### **Below is the rake task code:**

```
task :cleansed_log => :environment do
raw_logs = Searchlog.find_by_sql("SELECT q from searchlogs")
flag = 0
pres_log, prev_log = "", ""
if raw_logs.count > 1
  raw_logs.each do |raw_log|

    if flag == 0
      prev_log = raw_log.q
      flag = 1

    else

      pres_log = raw_log.q
      if pres_log =~ /#{prev_log}/
        prev_log = pres_log

      else
        @cleansedlog = Cleansedlog.new(:keyword => prev_log)
        @cleansedlog.save

        prev_log = pres_log
      end

    end
  end
  @cleansedlog = Cleansedlog.new(:keyword => pres_log)
  @cleansedlog.save

  Searchlog.destroy_all

end

end
```

---

Below is the cron job which calls above rake task:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: cleansedlog
# 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd       /var/www/prodsite//releases/20110715035538 && RAILS_ENV=production rake cleansed_log -- silent >> /work/saptcodes/cron.log 2>&1'
# End Whenever generated tasks for: cleansedlog
```

---

Comment: show rake task code and show how do you call it

Comment: Are you using rvm on your production server and have scheduled the rake task through cron. I recently faced problems with rvm-rake-cron.

Comment: I am not using rvm. Calling the rake task using a cron job. I have updated the question with rake task code and cron job details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but do you pass `RAILS_ENV` option to you rake task?

For example:

```
rake logs:destroy RAILS_ENV='production'
```

Comment: Yes, I do pass RAILS_ENV. In fact I read from the logs model in the same rake task before moving them to a archive table. Reading from the model is working fine in the same task.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
model.delete_all
```

Careful since this will not honor callbacks, dependent associations and goes straight to the database.

I have encountered similar behavior sometimes with destroy_all, especially in migrations.

Comment: I have tried model.delete_all as well. That is also not working in production but working fine in development.